# using string variable with REGEXP select pymysql query in python3

Tags: python, mysql, django

i have a chat bot django web application that take the user input and tries to find the matching input in the DB then retrieve the corresponding output.

**This is a part of chatbot.py code:**

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 import re,string,sys
 import codecs
 import types
 import nltk
 import csv
 import pymysql
 from nltk import pos_tag
 from nltk.tokenize import  regexp_tokenize
 from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
 from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer
 from chatbotx1.arabic_const import *
 from chatbotx1.normalize import *
 from chatbotx1.stemming import *
 from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
 from chatbotx1.ar_ghalat import *
 from chat.models import chat, user_info

 # initialize the connection to the female_database
 conn = pymysql.connect("***","***","***","***") 
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 conn.text_factory = str

 def run_conversation_male():
       last_B =' '.join(chat.objects.values_list('chatbot_response', flat=True).latest('id')) 
       H =  ' '.join(chat.objects.values_list('user_iput', flat=True).latest('id'))
       New_H= ' '.join(PreProcess_text(H))
       cursor.execute('SELECT respoce FROM Male_Conversation_Engine WHERE request REGEXP?',[New_H])
       reply = cursor.fetchone() 
       if reply:
          B8=reply[0]
          new_data(H,B8)  
          ID = chat.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).latest('id')
          chat.objects.filter(id=ID).update(chatbot_response=B8)
```

Before i was using sqlite3, but now after using Mysql i got this error message:

```
  TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I have tried this solution:

```
  openconnect = pymysql.connect(host='xxxx',port=3306,user='xxx',passwd='xxx',db='xxxx',charset='utf8')
```

and i got this error message:

```
  pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;)
```

**(PS: I am using Python3.5,Mysql, pymysql,Django10, and the text is in Arabic language)**

Comment: remove `?` from `REGEXP?` and check for mysql syntax for `REGEXP`.

Comment: @EminMastizada thank you, i have tried removing ? but it still the same string formation error.Also, i tried to find the  mysql syntax for REGEXP but i didn't find and resource

Comment: Mysql Document for REGEXP: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: @EminMastizada That is very helpful thank you. yes i came across this page and could find a way to include a string variable in the query. Also, i have tried LIKE and got this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character

Comment: Check and make sure your database (or at least table) uses UTF-8 encoding. Usually it needs to be selected while creating database schema and tables.

Comment: yes i've checked it also and when i created the DB the encoding was UTF-8 by default

Answer (score 0):

Problem with syntax is that, `cursor.execute` don't know where to put `New_H`. You need %s to mark place for that variable.
Try to change your SQL to this one:

```
SELECT respoce FROM Male_Conversation_Engine WHERE request REGEXP %s
```

Comment: i got this error again: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\\u0631' in position 68: ordinal not in range(256) `